# Export Hyperlink to pdf file from iTextSharp library in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have problem on export in pdf file one GridView in c# asp net with [iTextSharp Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

In the last column I expected the Hyperlink, but in the output pdf I have the link truncated and a non-existent connection which responds with an error "page not found".

Please check the attachment image and code c#.

Anybody know how can I resolve this?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="hlKvm" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlKvm" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Kvm").ToString() %>'
                ImageUrl='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Kvm").ToString()) ? "/mac/Images/TRKO8.png" : "/Images/download.gif")%>'
                ToolTip='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Kvm").ToString()) ? "" : "")%>'
                Target="_blank" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Transparent">
            </asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>



    cellText = (gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[16].FindControl("hlKvm") as HyperLink).NavigateUrl;
```

**Edit #1**

This is the code for Anchor method, please check the attached image and the code below.

```
                        cellText = (gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[16].FindControl("hlKvm") as HyperLink).NavigateUrl;
                        string imagePath = Server.MapPath((gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[16].FindControl("hlKvm") as HyperLink).ImageUrl);
                        iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
                        Chunk cImage = new Chunk(image, 0, 0, false);
                        Anchor anchor = new Anchor(cImage);
                        anchor.Reference = cellText.ToString();
                        table.AddCell(anchor);
```

[image]

**Edit #2**

If try the your **Option 1** the output is:

[image]

If try the your **Option 2** the output is:

```
Invalid URI: The URI is empty. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.

Source Error: 


Line 772:                            iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
Line 773:                            Chunk cImage = new Chunk(image, 0, 0, false);
Line 774:                            cImage.SetAction(new PdfAction(new Uri(cellText.ToString())));
Line 775:                            table.AddCell(new Phrase(cImage));
Line 776:
```

If try the your **Option 2** with checked **cellText** is null the output is:

[image]

But the image is not aligned to gridview ...

Comment: You need to create an `Anchor` or a link `PdfAnnotation` if you want to add a hyperlink. It would surprise me if anyone would be surprised by the behavior you are describing. It's very normal that the link is broken, because (1) you don't provide a link, (2) in your case, you can click the link, because the viewer converts text that starts with http:// into a link: (a) not every viewer will do that, (b) you only provide part of the URL, hence the link is broken.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie hi, thank you for reply, I have tried with Anchor image but the output is lost the alignment. Do you have example to PdfAnnotation ?

Comment: (1.) `Anchor` works, so please show us what you've tried. Maybe you're doing it wrong. (2.) Check out [these examples](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C07). The LinkActions example uses `Chunk.SetAnchor()`, the MoviePosters1 examples uses `Annotation`, the TimeTableAnnotations2 example uses `PdfAnnotation`. Actually, once you start reading the documentation (or should I say *if* you start reading the documentation), you can find quite some examples...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks, please see **Edit #1** in my first question-

Comment: Edit #1 didn't work in old versions, so maybe you're using an obsolete, unsupported version (if so, make sure that it's legally OK to use it: you need at least iTextSharp version 5 if you want a version of which the IP is 100% clear). I'll create an answer with some alternative code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have this code:

```
cellText = (gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[16].FindControl("hlKvm") as HyperLink).NavigateUrl;
string imagePath = Server.MapPath((gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[16].FindControl("hlKvm") as HyperLink).ImageUrl);
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
Chunk cImage = new Chunk(image, 0, 0, false);
Anchor anchor = new Anchor(cImage);
anchor.Reference = cellText.ToString();
table.AddCell(anchor);
```

Using `Anchor` in the context of a `PdfPCell` didn't work in old versions of iTextSharp. I think this was fixed quite a while ago.

However, there are some alternative ways to achieve the same result:

**Option 1:** Use `SetAction` instead of `Anchor`:

```
cellText = (gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[16].FindControl("hlKvm") as HyperLink).NavigateUrl;
string imagePath = Server.MapPath((gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[16].FindControl("hlKvm") as HyperLink).ImageUrl);
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
Chunk cImage = new Chunk(image, 0, 0, false);
cImage.SetAction(new PdfAction(new Uri(cellText.ToString())));
table.AddCell(new Phrase(cImage));
```

The `PdfAction` takes an URL and `SetAction` will create a link annotation to open that URL.

**Option 2:** Make the image clickable:

```
cellText = (gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[16].FindControl("hlKvm") as HyperLink).NavigateUrl;
string imagePath = Server.MapPath((gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[16].FindControl("hlKvm") as HyperLink).ImageUrl);
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
Annotation annotation = new Annotation(0, 0, 0, 0, cellText);
image.Annotation = annotation;
table.AddCell(image);
```

There may be other options, but start by trying these two and let me know if they work for you.

**Update #1:** (Corresponding with your Edit #2, second part)

What if you try to create a `PdfPCell`:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(image, true);
table.AddCell(cell);
```

Now, the `image` object will be scaled so that it fits the cell correctly.

**Update #2:** (Corresponding with your Edit #2, first part)

This is not an iText exception:

> Invalid URI: The URI is empty.

This problem is probably caused by the value of `cellText.ToString()`. If this isn't a valid URL (e.g. because it is empty), then you get an exception.

**PROOF OF CONCEPT**

I have written a proof of concept in the hope that I can convince you that what I am saying is true and in the hope that other readers believe me when I say that iText is working correctly (instead of believing you when you claim the opposite).

This is my example: [ImagesLinksTable](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/ImagesLinksTable)

This is the resulting PDF: [images_links_table.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/images_links_table.pdf)

In this example I use three different techniques. They all work:

**Technique 1:** Using `Anchor`:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(IMG);
Chunk c = new Chunk(img, 0, 0, true);
Anchor anchor = new Anchor(c);
anchor.setReference("http://lowagie.com/");
table.addCell(anchor);
```

I create an `Image`, I wrap it into a `Chunk`, and I use this `Chunk` in an `Anchor`. I add the `Anchor` to the table. This works without any problem.

**Technique 2:** Using `setAction()`:

```
Chunk c2 = new Chunk(img, 0, 0, true);
c2.setAction(new PdfAction("http://itextpdf.com"));
table.addCell(new Phrase(c2));
```

In this case, we don't use an `Anchor`, but I define the link as an action. Why do I create a new `Chunk` object? If I use the same `Chunk` as before, then I can only use one URL for that `Chunk`.

**Technique 3:**

```
Image img2 = Image.getInstance(IMG);
Annotation a = new Annotation(0, 0, 0, 0, "http://lowagie.com/bio");
img2.setAnnotation(a);
table.addCell(img2);
```

In this case, I define the link at the level of the image, but here I also have to create a new image. If I'd reuse the image used before, then all images would point to the same link.

This is what my PDF looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the images fit nicely into the cells. You can easily tweak the code to change the size of the `Image` and/or to make sure the image scales (or doesn't scale) to match the size of the cell.

My example was written in Java, but if you use the iTextSharp port and if you port my example to C#, you'll get the same result.

Comment: Many thanks for suggestions, please see **Edit #2** in my first question

Comment: I use iTextSharp version 5.5.7 - 17/09/2015

Comment: That's strange. I haven't noticed this in the Java version. I'll have to ask the people who did the C# port to test this.

Comment: Okay than you for help, but when I have more hyperlinks in the gridview on only first the image is correct, The next hyperlinks move onward the columns. If you want I can post the full code in c#. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not a C# developer, I am a 100% pure Java developer. Posting the full code in C# only makes sense in the context of support at iText Group, but you can only do that if you have a support contract.

Comment: As you can see, I was able to create a proof of concept that works as expected. I wasn't able to reproduce the problems you describe. I can not fix problems that don't exist.